# UIScrollView Not Responding after Refresh if Count is not Equal to Initial Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, paging

I am getting a very strange problem. I have a View that the top half is a UITableView and the Bottom is a UIScrollView with Paging Enabled (2 Pages total) So basically if you tap on one of the cells in the TableView the data will populate in views below. I am pulling the requests that populate the UITableView from the web.

When I load the application everything works fine and refresh works fine.
For some reason when I delete a cell form the tableview and perform a reload, my scrollview paging stop responding... I have no idea what is causing this. The data will still populate on the view, but I can't page to the other view of information.

I'm not sure what code to post as when I perform the refresh, it's just
doing this:

```
[Request allOpenRequestsWithBlock:^(NSArray *requestsFromWeb, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil), nil] show];
         [self performSelector:@selector(stopLoading) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Number of Open Requests: %d", [requestsFromWeb count]);
        [self.openRequestFromNet removeAllObjects];
        self.openRequestFromNet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:requestsFromWeb];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        //self.openRequestLoaded = true;


         [self performSelector:@selector(stopLoading) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }

} forEID: idNumberFromLogin];
```

It seems like if the number of openRequests are different from the initial number of openRequests my ScrollView freezes but the scrollview will still update with data, just paging is gone.

I have no idea why?!

The only time that the UITableViewController class even affects the UIScrollView is when it populates views within the ScrollView by sending a NSNotification

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     MyOpenRequestCell *cell = [[MyOpenRequestCell alloc] init];
    cell = (MyOpenRequestCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMyDidSelectNotification object:[cell.requestID text]];
}
```

I am sensing it is possibly an issue with the pointer? But I'm really only sending it a NSString that is not directly used with the UIScrollView/Views inside. It is used to make another call to get data for that Request Number.

Thanks!

Comment: The first question: is this code always performed on the main thread ?

Comment: @A-Live I don't think so? This is a Asynchronous call, so I am only calling reloadData only after the call has been completed. It seems to work perfectly fine as long as the number of requests that come fro the value stays the same... the values can change but the count has to stay the same. Why it is affecting my scrollview I have no idea... since the scrollview is not involved in the TableView Refresh at all....

Comment: Then the first steps should be to move the UI code to the main thread, that must be `reloadData` and whichever method affects scrollView appearance. Changing UI from detached threads might be the reason of any sort of problems.

Comment: @A-Live the reloadData does not affect the scrollview, it just affects the UITableView. The only part that does modify the scrollview is when the UITableView is selected and I use a NSNotification (see updated post)

Comment: @A-Live I figured out the problem after going through the debugger. It seems like the Frame of my UIScrollView gets changed to just the width of the screen, so it is no longer paging... I still have no idea why the UIScrollView changes values back to the default screensize rather than the expanded size.

Comment: Check autoresizing mask and contentSize then, or are you using the new  auto layout ?

Comment: @A-Live Yes I am using AutoLayout.
I don't use autoresizing mask in code, but I do use `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);` in ViewDidLoad, but I had to add `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);` it again after the refresh to get it to start paging again, but this solution seems weird... I don't know why the contentSize gets changed when the only place I set it was in ViewDidLoad and it calculates correctly.